# data binding with dynamic data not working in knockout

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I am using the following code to generate a table with the data-binding.

```
$('<tr><td><table><tbody id="dynamic" data-bind="template:{name: \'tableView\', foreach: dat}"></tbody></table></td></tr>').insertAfter($(string).closest('tr'));
```

The table is getting created but the data-binding is not working.

I have already tried

```
ko.applyBindings(myViewModel(),$('#dynamic')[0]);
```

but its not working.

Comment: try like this http://jsfiddle.net/supercool/LkqTU/26679/ . you need to re-apply bindings via cleanNode.

Comment: Please update your question and include minimal, yet *enough* code to reproduce your scenario.

Comment: @supercool `cleanNode` is not recommended; it is an internal routine. Your fiddle works fine without it, using the OP's method: http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/26680/

Comment: @RoyJ you seem to be using different id's in applybindings else it will throw definite error .

Comment: @RoyJ i agree `cleanNode` is not advisable but when there are templates/with bindings it work fine .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, take a look at the [`html` binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/html-binding.html), which is preferable to inserting HTML via jQuery. You can make a custom binding handler that wraps the `html` binding and applies bindings whenever the html is updated. This might work for you:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.boundHtml = {
    init:ko.bindingHandlers.html.init,
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, data, context) {
        ko.bindingHandlers.html.update(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, data, context);
        var nodes = element.children;
        for (var i=0; i<nodes.length; ++i) {
            ko.applyBindings(context, nodes[i]);
        }
    }
};
```

A [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zLfgu8s2/).